# Hide/Encapsulate all attributes from an inherited class while keeping functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to hide or nest the `Cat` attributes within `Animal` while still being able to run the jump function? Specifically I would like to the output of `vars(test)` to only be the age. I'm sure I could hard code which specific attributes to not output by defining a custom `__str__` but I will have a lot of attributes for `Cat/Animal` and I don't want to manually add an exception for each individual attribute. I also won't have access to the `Cat` class.

```
def Jump():
    print('Jumped!')

class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.feet = 4
        self.jump = Jump

class Animal(Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        Cat.__init__(self)
        self.age = 3

test = Animal()
test.jump()
print(vars(test))
```

Output:

> Jumped {'feet': 4, 'jump': , 'age': 3}

This is just code to illustrate what I'm trying to do. In reality `Cat` represents a published python module and `Animal` represents my custom one.

Comment: Well typically "*hiding*" stuff is not very Pythonic, but yes, you can do that.

Comment: As a side note, you have a terminological snafu in your class design. `Animal(Cat)` means "an Animal is a kind of a Cat," while in reality it's just the opposite.

Comment: Probably encapsulating all the Cat attributes within an Animal.cat attribute would be best but I would like to still be able to call test.jump() and not test.cat.jump()

Comment: @als9xd: I think you misunderstand how inheritance works. There is no `.cat` at all here, and tbh, an explicit call like `Cat.__init__(self)` is a serious antipattern.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know im saying I would ideally like there to be a .cat attribute within Animal that has all the Cat attributes. But I still want to be able to call Animal.jump() even though it's encapsulated within the theoretical Animal.cat attribute

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think the OP is saying that they know they could, and probably should, change their code to do `self.cat = Cat()` instead of inheriting from `Cat` and super-initializing it, but what they _don't_ know is how to do that but then automatically delegate `animal.jump` to `animal.cat.jump`.

Comment: @abarnert Maybe `self.cat = Cat()` is what I want because I don't want to have to hard code anything into Animals every time anything is added to Cat (since Cat may change in the future and it also has alot of attributes that will clutter the Animal class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your relationship so that `Animal` no longer *is-a* `Cat`, but instead *has-a* `Cat`, then you're right, `animal.jump()` will no longer work.

There are many ways around this. Given how odd this design already is, in so many different ways, I have no idea which is most appropriate, so I'll just list a whole bunch of them.

The first group are ways to explicitly delegate just `jump`.

The "normal" way:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = Cat()
    def jump(self):
        return self.cat.jump()
```

Copy the per-instance function:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = Cat()
        self.jump = self.cat.jump
```

Delegate to the per-instance function:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = Cat()
        self.jump = lambda: self.cat.jump()
```

Per-instance bound method:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = Cat()
        self.jump = (lambda self: self.cat.jump()).__get__(self)
```

Dynamic lookup:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = Cat()
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'jump':
            return getattr(self.cat, name)
        raise AttributeError
```

Dynamic bound method generation:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = Cat()
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'jump':
            return (lambda self: getattr(self.cat, name)()).__get__(self)
        raise AttributeError
```

Of course all of these only delegate `jump` specifically. What if you wanted to delegate to *all* `Cat` functions, methods, and maybe other attributes, without necessarily knowing what they are in advance? Well, it should be obvious how to adapt most of these, so I'll just show two.

Dynamic lookup:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = Cat()
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.cat, name)
```

Semi-static inspection that does complicated reflection on the different possible kinds of things we might want to delegate:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = cat
        for name, value in inspect.getmembers(self.cat):
            if name.startswith('_'): continue
            if inspect.ismethod(value):
                value = (lambda self: value()).__get__(self)
            elif callable(value):
                value = lambda: value()
            else:
                value = copy.copy(value)
            setattr(self, name, value)
```